# Attempting to filter through itemset

Tags: python, parsing, tuples

I have an itemset called `data`, where in every itemset is the first element of a tuple. An example of one instance looks like this:

```
(('5', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333)
```

I am trying to filter through the itemset in two parts:

Part 1 - I'm trying to filter out the itemset so that the only instances remaining are ones which contain '<=X' within the actual itemset (Within the first part of the tuple for each instance).

**Code for Part 1:**

```
for i in data:
    if "<=X" not in i[0]:
        del i
```

Part 2 - I'm now trying to take the remaining items and filter it in such a way that the only sets remaining are ones where there are *three or more* items in the itemset.

**Code for Part 2:**

```
for i in data:
    if len(i[0]) < 3:
        del i
```

Despite this, when I try to run the above code I end up with an empty list, but I have looked through the list with a variable inspector and I have seen that there *are* occurrences of this, but they don't show up after filtering. What's wrong?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this works for you:

```
list(filter(lambda x: len(x[0]) >= 3, filter(lambda x: '<=X' in x[0], lst)))
```

or, combining both conditions:

```
list(filter(lambda x: len(x[0]) >= 3 and '<=X' in x[0], lst))
```

Also, notice that `del` in your loops really do not do what (I think) you want them to accomplish:

```
In [175]: data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [176]: for k in data:
     ...:     del k
     ...:     

In [177]: data
Out[177]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Moreover, modifying a list while looping over it is a bad idea.

### EXAMPLE:

```
In [183]: lst = [(('5', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333),
     ...:(('Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333)]

In [184]: list(filter(lambda x: len(x[0]) < 3, filter(lambda x: '<=X' in x[0], lst)))
Out[184]: [(('Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333)]
```

Comment: I see. In your solution, you use `< 3`. Does that mean it deletes every set with less than three items? In which case won't your second filter delete every itsemset that contains '<=X' as well? Lastly, would it be better to store the result in another variable, or will this store the result in `lst`?

Comment: @tushariyer I made a mistake and I fixed it in my last edit.

Comment: @tushariyer I also added an example

Comment: @AGNGazer Python 2 example though right? `filter` doesn't return a list in Python 3.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I have improved compatibility in my latest edit

Comment: @AGNGazer I see that but now wouldn't it be less efficient in Python 2? Wouldn't you be creating two lists instead of one? That is one advantage of using list comprehensions instead of `filter`, cross-compatibility with the same code.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Alright, I combined both conditions into a single one. Thanks

Comment: @AGNGazer That's good but that isn't what I meant. `filter(...)` returns a list in Python 2 but you are then wrapping it in `list(filter(...))`. Wouldn't that make another copy of the list created by `filter(...)` (in Python 2)? In Python 3, it seems like it would only create one list.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I hope Python 2 is smart enough to see that `list()` called on a list need to return input. Loss of efficiency would be minimal/negligible.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> part_1_data = [
...     (('5', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('6', 'Generous', '<=Y'), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('7', 'Generous', '<=Z'), 0.33333333333333)
... ]
>>> part_1 = [elem for elem in part_1_data if '<=X' in elem[0]]
>>> part_1
[(('5', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333)]


>>> part_2_data = [
...     (('5', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('6', 'Generous'), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('7',), 0.33333333333333)
... ]
>>> part_2 = [elem for elem in part_2_data if len(elem[0]) >= 3]
>>> part_2
[(('5', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333)]


>>> both = [
...     (('1', 'Generous', '<=X', 4), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('2', 'Generous', '<=Y'), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('3', 'Generous', '<=Z'), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('4', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('5', 'Generous'), 0.33333333333333),
...     (('6',), 0.33333333333333)
... ]
>>> [elem for elem in both if len(elem[0]) >= 3 and '<=X' in elem[0]]
[(('1', 'Generous', '<=X', 4), 0.33333333333333), (('4', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333)]
```

Comment: Wow! I never thought to tackle it like this. Would I be able to just store the result in another variable and be fine?

Comment: @tushariyer It would probably be easier to just save them in a new variable.  Modifying a list while you iterate over it is never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks lettuce! I love learning ways to manipulate lists like this

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, you can use unpacking in a list comprehension:

```
s = [(('5', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333)]
final_results = [((*b, c), a) for (*b, c), a in s if len(b)+1 >=3 and c == '<=X']
```

Comment: `[v for v in lst if ('<=X' in v[0] and len(v[0]) >= 3)]` works in Python 2 as well

Comment: @AGNGazer you may be running a different version from me, however, `*` is not valid syntax in Python3 when used for list/tuple unpacking.

Comment: I think your code is more complicated because you want to unpack *all* items *assuming* '<=X' is in `c` but OP does not mention that: '<=X' can be anywhere. So, if you want to do any unpacking the following would be enough: `[(v, a) for v, a in lst if '<=X' in v and len(v) >= 3]`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify sequence while iterating throught it. See [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406) for further info.

IMO you should consider using list comprehensions, which have many advantages over your current approach.

**Firstly:** performance. [list comprehensions are significantly faster](http://leadsift.com/loop-map-list-comprehension/), [Speed of list comprehension vs for loop with append](https://gist.github.com/benhoyt/2647005), [Efficiency of list comprehensions](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/), [Are these list-comprehensions written the fastest possible way?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23441/).

**Secondly:**
 code readability. list comprehensions syntax is a way more compact, and thus easier to read, that makes it more "pythonic". [List Comprehensions Explained Visually](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

**By the way:** Even if modifying sequence while iterating it would be good idea, in most cases keeping input (original) and output (processed) datasets separately is very convenient, and allows to derive multiple further outputs (by filtering against different conditions). Replacing original data with processed/filtered makes further changes to filtering conditions impossible, in other hand it's sometimes advantageous when processing input data is very time and/or resource consuming (or, simply, if it's absolutely sure that original dataset won't be needed anymore).

**Further reading:** (performance optimizations and pitfalls): [Generators or List comprehensions](http://dvalts.io/code/optimisation/2017/08/10/Generators-or-Listcomps.html), [Beware the Python generators](https://igorpartola.com/programming/beware-the-python-generators/)

Quick and simple (though a bit dirty) solution to filter data structure described in your question:

```
In [1]: dat = [(('1', 'Generous', '<=X', 4), 0.33333333333333),
   ...:  (('2', 'Generous', '<=Y'), 0.33333333333333),
   ...:  (('3', 'Generous', '<=Z'), 0.33333333333333),
   ...:  (('4', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333),
   ...:  (('5', 'Generous'), 0.33333333333333),
   ...:  (('6',), 0.33333333333333)]
   ...: 
   ...: result = [itm for itm in dat if ('<=X' in itm[0]) and (len(itm[0]) >= 3)]

In [2]: dat
Out[2]: 
[(('1', 'Generous', '<=X', 4), 0.33333333333333),
 (('2', 'Generous', '<=Y'), 0.33333333333333),
 (('3', 'Generous', '<=Z'), 0.33333333333333),
 (('4', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333),
 (('5', 'Generous'), 0.33333333333333),
 (('6',), 0.33333333333333)]

In [3]: result
Out[3]: 
[(('1', 'Generous', '<=X', 4), 0.33333333333333),
 (('4', 'Generous', '<=X'), 0.33333333333333)]
```